# PCI DSS security - SRED protection

Tags: security, pci-dss, pci-compliance

i have a simple question...

Using a PCI PTS 3.0 hardware that secures sensitive data with SRED procedure with DUKPT double lenght TDES keys. Is the resulted encrypted data SAFE ?

Let say would it be considered safe if you would send it over unsecured TCP? over unsecured routers? over internet via TCP? Posted on pastebin :) ?

Or is there a MUST for additional security on communication pathways? Does SSL still needs to be used ? Why ? where does it says so?

I really cannot find relevant info when using SRED is that itself ENOUGH and considered PCI DSS 3.0 safe?

Edited:
To simplify... Is TripleDed Dukpt encrypted track2 data transferred via tcp on local lan considered safe?

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 3):

Over a network, 3DES/DUKPT can securely encrypt track 2 data.  A passive attacker would not be able to decrypt the message and obtain the credit card numbers.

However, DUKPT does not protect against replay attacks.  You should use additional encryption to ensure transaction message integrity.

An attacker could modify other transaction data without changing the encrypted track 2 data.  For example, an attacker could intercept a transaction message and extract the encrypted track 2 data.  The attacker could create a new transaction for a different amount with the same encrypted track 2 data.  The attacker could then submit the modified transaction in place of the actual transaction.

Comment: Wow I never noticed, we can do a replay attack. Since DUKPT is state less an attacker can do it easily.